# How to connect to a cross domain API using javascript without CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, jsonp

I'm looking for a trick to access an API on a server that I don't have access to using html/javascript. Usually browsers block this for safety reasons. Public APIs like google therefore support CORS headers that let the browser know that the source can be trusted.

I need the solution to be client side because the external API might not be accessible to the hosting server. I do not have access to the API providing server. Therefore options like JSONP and enabling CORS headers are not viable options.

I need a bit of creativity; options I'm considering:

- building an application in c# or whatever that can connect to the server and then open a browser. I don't like this option much
- Loading a java applet in the page that does the server connection. Also not really great (who uses java appletsanymore)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Nothing short of a client application of some kind (that includes browser plugins) will be able to bypass the restriction. Java applets cannot unless granted the right explicitly.

Comment: a client application would be fine but is there a way to do this without having to ask the user to install anything? maybe flash would work?

Comment: No. If there were, what security would domain isolation provide when any site could bypass it without having the user do some action to allow it? Flash has the same restrictions as Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple server what acts as a proxy to provide you the required endpoints. It can be implemented in anything you can host on a server in the same domain like PHP, NodeJS, etc.. Since it won't run in the browser it will have no problem to access external servers.

If all your target devices support HTML5 you can use window.postMessage() too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: The question says he can't use a server-side proxy.